# Is there a way to get my full listening history from the Spotify API?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I've been trying to get my listening history from Spotify using spotipy, but unfortunately the recently-played endpoint is limited to 50 tracks.

Spotify obviously has to store this data because they use it when displaying my year-end listening stats, and I know there are some third-party websites that also use it (e.g: https://www.statsforspotify.com/), which means it has to be accessible somehow...

Comment: I have not found a good answer to this. Maybe contact info@statsforspotify.com and see if they are willing to help? You can download your own data, but it requires a request and multiple days, which statsforspotify obviously does not do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that uses a cron to collect data, so it would get what you need from the point its set up onward: https://gist.github.com/SamL98/c1200a30cdb19103138308f72de8d198

Unfortunately, there is no way to programmatically access your full streaming history unless you set up a collector like the one mentioned above. However, you can manually request a copy of your history from Spotify from the link at the bottom of this page: https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/account/privacy/